# Search query and search result in DomainDrivenDesign

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a web application with news posts. Those news posts should be searchable. **In context of DDD what kind of buililng block are search query and search result?**

### These are my thoughts

They both don't have identity, therefore they are not Entities. But the absence of identity doesn't imply they are Value Object. As Eric Evans states:

> However, if we think of this category of object as just the absence of identity, we haven't added much to our toolbox or vocabulary. In fact, these objects have characteristics of their own and their own significance to the model. *These are the objects that describe things.*

I would like to say that both are value objects, but I'm not sure. What confuses me are examples that I've found on Internet. Usualy value object are part of other entities, they are not "standalone". [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) gives for example Money or date range object. [Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/value_object_vs_data_transfer) event compares them to enums.

If search result would be considered value object, that would be value object that consists of entities. I'm not sure that's completely alright.

I don't think they are DataTransferObject. Because we are not current concerned with transferring data between layers, but we are concerned with their meaning for the model in absence of layer.

I don't think search query is command. Because it's not a request for change.
As stated on [CQRS](http://cqrs.nu/Faq)

> People request changes to the domain by sending commands.

I'm trying to use and learn DDD, can someone clarify this problem to me? Where did I go wrong with reasoning?

Comment: Are you sure that search query and search resukt are part of your domain language? Isn't that just a technical thing (implementation matter) of your app?

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is that querying is probably not part of your domain.  The domain model is not there to serve queries, it is there to enforce invariants in your domain.  Since by nature queries are read-only, there are no invariants to enforce, so why complicate things?  I think where people usually go wrong with DDD is that they assume since they are "doing DDD" every aspect of the system must be handled by a domain model.  DDD is there to help with the complex business rules and should only be applied when/where you actually have them.  Also, you can and probably should have many models to support each bounded context.  But that's another discussion.

It's interesting that you mention CQRS because what does that stand for?  Command query responsibility segregation.  So if commands use the domain model, and query responsibility is segregated from that, what does that tell you to do?  The answer is, do whatever is easiest to query and display that data.  If select * from news table filled to dataset works, go with that.  If you prefer entity framework, go with that.  There is no need to get the domain model involved for queries.

One last point I'd like to make is I think a lot of people struggle with DDD by applying it to situations where there aren't many business invariants to enforce and the domain model ends up looking a lot like the database.  Be sure you are using the right tool for the job and not over complicating things. Also, you should only apply DDD in the areas of your system where these invariants exist.  It's not an all or nothing scenario.

Comment: Yeah, it did set me up straight. Thanks.